# Como pausar uma thread e executar outra thread?

Tags: java, thread

Olá, preciso entender como faço para uma thread pausar sua execução e outra thread começar a executar?

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class AB1AB2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Semaphore semaforo = new Semaphore(1);

    MutableString ms = new MutableString();

    Thread thrd0 = new Thread(new Accumulator(ms, semaforo), "THREAD 0");
    Thread thrd1 = new Thread(new Accumulator(ms, semaforo), "THREAD 1");

    thrd0.start();
    thrd1.start();

    try{
        thrd0.join();
        thrd1.join();
    }catch(InterruptedException ie){}

    System.out.println(ms.getOrdem());
  }
}
```

Esse trecho de código cria duas threads e executa as seguintes classes:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class MutableString {
    private String ordem ="";

    public String getOrdem() {
        return ordem;
    }

    public void setString(){
        Thread teste = Thread.currentThread();
        if(teste.getName() == "THREAD 0"){
            ordem += "A";
            teste.interrupt();
            ordem += "a";
        } 
        Thread teste2 = Thread.currentThread();
        String teste2Name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        if(teste.getName() == "THREAD 1") {
            ordem += "B";
            teste2.interrupt();
            ordem += "b";
        }
    }
}

class Accumulator implements Runnable{
    private MutableString sharedValue;
    private Semaphore semaforo;
    private int threadAtual;

    public Accumulator(MutableString acc, Semaphore sempahore) {
        this.sharedValue = acc;
        this.semaforo = sempahore;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            semaforo.acquire();
            sharedValue.setString();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            semaforo.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Eu estou tentando fazer o seguinte:  A thread0 vai e escreve "A" na variável `ordem` da classe `MutableString` e aí, preciso que após ela acrescentar a letra "A", a execução da thread pare, e comece a executar a thread1, que vai acrescentar "B" á String ordem, logo após a Thread0 volta e escreve "a" e logo após a thread1 volta e escreve "b", finalizando a strig ordem com: "ABab", tentei utilizar `interrupted`, mas não obtive sucesso

Comment: não sei se seria o ideal, mas já tentou usar o `sleep()`?

Comment: @Sabão eu tentei, usei sleep para a thread0, mas ele só fica parado esperando, como faço para executar a thread1, enquando a thread0 está dormindo?

Answer (score 0):

Bom, a possível solução para seu problema seria utilizar os métodos da Thread, que são wait() e notify().

Quando a thread0 escrever "A" na variável ordem da classe MutableString, você adormece ela com o método wait(), isto a fará dormir. Logo após, a thread1 vai acrescentar "B" à String ordem, e neste momento, você irá chamar o método notify() para avisar à thread0 para que ela acorde, e, em seguida, usar o wait() na thread1, que irá adormece-la. E assim sucessivamente.

Não sei se você conseguiu entender o raciocínio para o seu problema. Mas a ideia é essa.

Comment: A minha dúvida é a seguinte, como faço para executar Thread1, depois dechamar o wait na Thread0? Pois tentei e o programa fica parado esperando o wait acabar e ai volta a thread0 e depois a thread1